# sharepoint list item event handlers - identify source

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a web part that updates a list item. User can also update the item from the screen. I use SPListItem.Update method.

I have event handlers attached with the list.

In the item updated/updating method ... is there a way to know whether the user has updated the listitem from the screen or from my web part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a column to your list and updated the value in your code when the list is updated from the webpart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I had thought of this. But it is a bit dirty. for example, you would need to revert the value back on updating (so that subsequent saves from Sharepoitn lists do not hold this value). However, I still think it is the best option at this stage. +1 for now :)